# Azure Service Fabric Changing Setting After Deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, settings, azure-service-fabric

We're testing out service fabric and experiencing some issues.

Firstly the VM Type A1v2 comes with 10gb of HDD, however the issue is the log file takes up over 9gb of space almost immediately so deployments then fail with an out of disk space exception. So I've discovered I need to set the SharedLogSizeInMb to a smaller value as below:

```
            "fabricSettings": [
              {
                "name": "KtlLogger",
                "parameters": [
                  {
                      "name": "SharedLogSizeInMB",
                      "value": "256"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
```

The issue now is I am not sure how to apply this change. I can't seem to find a way to do it in the portal and when I download the powershell setup scripts from the portal in the Service Fabric setup process and run them to create a new Service Fabric instance it just gets as far as deploying and fails.

So my questions are:

1) How should I be adjusting this setting, I assume it can only be done via an ARM script?

2) Can these scripts only be used to create a new Service Fabric cluster or can you also somehow run them to just change a setting?

3) Should the vanilla script I export from Azure just work? The error messages I can find are very generic and non explanatory. Seems to just be an exception getting thrown in each VM when trying to create service fabric. I am pretty much using all the default settings nothing special.

Thanks,

Oliver

EDIT

My files in comment 2 just have this over and over.

2017/05/02-04:22:00.388,Info,4864,ImageStoreClient.ManagedFileLock,Obtained writer lock for D:\SvcFab\lock
2017/05/02-04:22:00.739,Info,4864,FabricDeployer.FabricDeployer,Executing Configure /fabricBinRoot:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin /fabricDataRoot:D:\SvcFab /fabricLogRoot:D:\SvcFab\Log /cm:C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode\1.0.0.35\TempClusterManifest.xml /oldClusterManifestString: /im:C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.ServiceFabricNode\1.0.0.35\InfrastructureManifest.xml /instanceId: /targetVersion: /nodeName: /nodeTypeName: /runAsType: /runAsAccountName: /runAsPassword: /serviceStartupType: /output: /currentVersion: /error: /bootstrapMSIPath: /machineName: /fabricPackageRoot: /jsonClusterConfigLocation: /enableCircularTraceSession:False
2017/05/02-04:22:02.452,Info,4864,FabricDeployer.FabricDeployer,Running operation System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ConfigureOperation
2017/05/02-04:22:02.576,Info,4864,FabricDeployer.FabricDeployer,Creating FabricDataRoot D:\SvcFab, if it doesn't exist on machine 
2017/05/02-04:22:02.576,Info,4864,FabricDeployer.FabricDeployer,Creating FabricLogRoot D:\SvcFab\Log, if it doesn't exist on machine 
2017/05/02-04:22:04.907,Info,4864,ImageStoreClient.ManagedFileLock,Released writer lock on D:\SvcFab\lock

My Event Logs this over and over.

Failed starting service, Error: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.AgentException: Configure node failed with code -1
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.StartFabricHostService(Boolean isBootstrapping)

ERROR: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.AgentException: Configure node failed with code -1
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.StartFabricHostService(Boolean isBootstrapping)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: After some more research my Infrastructure and Cluster manifests are identical (looking at the event log output on the server) however when I create the cluster from an ARM script and run it from the deploy powershell also provided when I download the templates it just throws a generic exception over and over in the event log and never gets further. Is there anywhere else Service Fabric logs more detailed output than the event log? It's a real mystery.

Comment: Found I can adjust the template straight through the portal (same screen where you download the template). However same deal, it fails.

My logs have the following over and over in D:/SvcFab/Log/Traces over and over and no other files inside is nothing meaningful and no errors.

fabricdeployer-636292957203376973.trace

Comment: We tried using A1_v2 for our primary node type and had the same experience. Our solution was the same as yours, though I don't recall whether it worked or not because we eventually switched to D1_v2.

Comment: Use D1 for initial deploy then scale back to a lesser VM.

Comment: There is an article on MS that describes how you can do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings